# How do I deal with what looks like a troll answer in the review queue?

Tags: discussion

I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24399877/957731) answer which was flagged as low quality.

The question was

> I have an array of integers, how do I calculate the corresponding heat
>   map color of each integer in javascript? Specifically, how to
>   implement this function:
>
> ```
> function getHeatMapColor(min, max, val) {   
>     // javascript codes here... 
> }
> ```
>
> Thank you!

And the answer that was flagged was

> Maybe try this:
>
> ```
> function doHeatMap(codes) {
>     return eval(codes); 
> }
> ```

To me this looks like obvious trolling. I think it's an attempt to be funny and suggest that the OP wants the SA community to write his code for him (which is probably true).

I feel the answer should be deleted but I don't know which of the options in the "Recommend Deletion" box would be appropriate. I'm leaning towards `This is commentary on another post, not an answer` but even as a comment it is pretty useless to the OP and unlikely to make him improve his question.

I ended up flagging the question as `too broad` and leave a comment to the OP asking him to clarify and skip the review.

Comment: Well this is awkward...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would have been auto flagged by the Community ♦ user due to the brevity of the non-code text in the answer and the reputation level (and/or history) of the user.

Just leave *No comment needed* selected if it is available to you:

[image]

Note that the review page already has clear instructions on what you are expected to do, just click the `more` link to the left of the buttons. Note that it doesn't mention flagging in any way.

[image]